# How group_by on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

I am pretty new to ROR and i'm in trouble to achieve this.

I have a Working_hour Model and a Merchant Model, where merchant has_many working_hours and working_hour belongs to Merchant, as follow:

```
class Merchant < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many   :working_hours, inverse_of: :merchant, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :working_hours, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Working hour table

```
create_table "working_hours", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "day"
  t.time     "open_time"
  t.time     "close_time"
  t.integer  "merchant_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.index ["merchant_id"], name: "index_working_hours_on_merchant_id"
end
```

The merchant can have two working_hours for the same day.

My view:

```
<% @merchant.working_hours.order(:day).each do |wh| %>
  <li>
    <%= t(:"date.abbr_day_names")[wh.day.to_i] %> : 
    <%= wh.open_time.to_formatted_s(:time)  %> -
    <%= wh.close_time.to_formatted_s(:time)  %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

When I display at the view ordered by day the data retrieved are:

```
Mon: 10:00-13:00
Mon: 17:00-20:00
Tue: 10:00-13:00
Tue: 17:00-21:00
Wed: 10:00-13:00
```

How can I group the working_hours by days and display this way:

```
Mon: 10:00-13:00 / 17:00-20:00
Tue: 10:00-13:00 / 17:00-21:00
Wed: 10:00-13:00
```

I watched the group_by tutorial from the Railscast, but I don't have a controller to working_hour Model. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you've got all the data you need in your view.  You just need to manipulate it properly.  Perhaps post the code from your view?

Comment: I edited my question. Is it simple to do that Ben?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ruby Enumerator's [group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) which will give you a new collection with the structure

```
{ 
  key: matching collection items (minus item grouped on), 
  key2: matching collection items (minus item grouped on)
}
```

This will mean your *.each* now will be applied to a Hash structure where the keys become either an integer or the thing you grouped by, day in this case which also happens to be an integer, and a subcollection that matches but has the attribute you grouped_by removed from it. So in your case you could rewrite

```
<% @merchant.working_hours.order(:day).each do |wh| %>
  <li>
    <%= t(:"date.abbr_day_names")[wh.day.to_i] %> : 
    <%= wh.open_time.to_formatted_s(:time)  %> -
    <%= wh.close_time.to_formatted_s(:time)  %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

as

```
<% @merchant.working_hours.order(:day).group_by(&:day).each do |day, whs| %>
  <%= t(:"date.abbr_day_names")[day.to_i] %> : 
  <%= whs.each_with_index do |wh, index| %>
    <li>
      <%= wh.open_time.to_formatted_s(:time)  %> -
      <%= wh.close_time.to_formatted_s(:time)  %>
    </li>
    <%# if we have more than one entry add slash %>
    <%= if index > 0 %>
      /
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note that this means all the grouping is being done on the ruby layer which will cause issues for large datasets, and also you're now in the ruby layer so you lose the AREL lazy loading features, e.g. sort will have to be done in ruby now vs applying a new SQL order to the "sub-collection". You'd ideally want to do a SQL group by but that's for another time.

Note I didn't test this code so it may blow up as is... YMMV and you'll have to reformat it a bit I'm sure.

Comment: Thank You. For now that works. =)

Do you recommend any materials for a newbie to learn about SQL group?

Comment: This is a good article to start ? https://alexpeattie.com/blog/grouping-activerecord-by-day-or-week-with-datetrunc

Comment: yeah mostly just google-fu or your local library. SQL hasn't changed much at the core so most of the stuff at your library should be relevant. If you use MySQL and want speed, this was recommended when I was starting out, http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do

Answer (score 1):

You can save the values in a hash and use it to print in the required format.

The **keys** in the hash will be `t(:"date.abbr_day_names")[wh.day.to_i]` and **values** will be ***array*** of `wh.open_time.to_formatted_s(:time) - wh.close_time.to_formatted_s(:time)`

```
@merchant_working_hours = {}
@merchant.working_hours.order(:day).each do |wh|
@merchant_working_hours[t(:"date.abbr_day_names")[wh.day.to_i].to_s] ||= []
@merchant_working_hours[t(:"date.abbr_day_names")[wh.day.to_i].to_s] = wh.open_time.to_formatted_s(:time).to_s + '-' +  wh.close_time.to_formatted_s(:time).to_s
```

end

You can then use **@merchant_working_hours** hash

```
<% @merchant_working_hours.each do |key,value| %>
<%= key: value%>
<% end %>
```

to print the values in the required format and you can use created at and updated at values or open time and close time to check for same day or not if you have data of over a week.